# Remove nested HTML tag inside <p> tags of an EPUB file

Tags: html, regex, epub

I have a html file with standard header

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title></title><link href="../Styles/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head><body><h1>Chapter 17</h1><div class="entry-content_wrap">
```

and some divs and a lot of normal text in p-tags, my problem is that inside these tags is another tag with text that belongs to the sentence

```
<p> Some text bla bla bla <other important text> bla.</p>
```

And I have a lot of files, I was looking for a regex expression that can remove the tags around  and leave anything else intact. I´m using Sigil which offers Find/Replace with Regex.

I have `(\<[^p]+\>)` at the moment which would match `<other important text>` but also a lot of HTML header and I somehow fail to only catch the surrounding <> of `other important text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you want to remove all the angle brackets that aren't part of a paragraph tag.
In Javascript I would do replace twice like so:

```
'your text'.replace(/<(?!(p>|\/p))/g, '').replace(/(?<!(<p|\/p))>/g, '')
```

I'm using the negative lookahead and the negative lookbehind feature.